# Populate excel worksheet (report) with variables selected on userform from separate worksheet (and maybe throw in a sneaky 'All' option)

Tags: vba, excel

Let me preface this with a huge thank you to anyone who takes the time to read this...

So I'm trying to make a simple 'Run Governance Report' button to pull data from one worksheet to another based on selected combobox variables in a Userform.

So far I have set up my two worksheets ("governance Reporting Data" and "Governance Report", a button "btnrun", and a userform "RunGovernance" set up.

What I cannot get to work is the following...

When the variables from the comboboxes are selected on the Userform, I cannot get it to populate data rows that only incorporate those variables...

I'd like to be able to select one or more of the variables from the combobox if possible and also like to put an "All" option in each of my comboboxes and have this grab All data available for that particular variable...

The code I have so far is as below;

```
Private Sub btnrun_Click()
    Dim sdsheet As Worksheet, grsheet As Worksheet
    Set sdsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Governance Reporting Data")
    Set grsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Governance Report")
    Dim match As Boolean
    match = False

    If sdsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
        sdlr = 2
    Else
        sdlr = sdsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    If grsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
        grlr = 2
    Else
        grlr = grsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    Me.Hide

    'find selected data and populate in report spreadsheet

    y = 2 ' starting row

    'month
    For x = 5 To sdlr
        If sdsheet.Cells(x, 2) = Me.cmbmonth Then
            'put on grsheet
            grsheet.Cells(y, 1) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 3)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 2) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 4)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 3) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 5)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 4) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 6)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 5) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 7)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 6) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 8)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 7) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 9)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 8) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 10)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 9) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 11)
            y = y + 1
        Else
            If sdsheet.Cells(x, 2) <> Me.cmbmonth Then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

        'provider
        If sdsheet.Cells(x, 4) = Me.cmbprovider Then
            'put on grsheet
            grsheet.Cells(y, 1) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 3)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 2) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 4)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 3) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 5)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 4) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 6)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 5) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 7)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 6) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 8)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 7) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 9)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 8) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 10)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 9) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 11)
            y = y + 1
        Else
            If grsheet.Cells(x, 4) <> Me.cmbprovider Then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

        'contract officer
        If sdsheet.Cells(x, 5) = Me.cmbcontractofficer Then
            'put on grsheet
            grsheet.Cells(y, 1) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 3)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 2) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 4)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 3) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 5)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 4) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 6)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 5) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 7)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 6) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 8)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 7) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 9)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 8) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 10)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 9) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 11)
            y = y + 1
        Else
            If grsheet.Cells(x, 5) <> Me.cmbcontractofficer Then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

        'program
        If sdsheet.Cells(x, 6) = Me.cmbprogram Then
            'put on grsheet
            grsheet.Cells(y, 1) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 3)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 2) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 4)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 3) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 5)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 4) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 6)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 5) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 7)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 6) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 8)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 7) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 9)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 8) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 10)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 9) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 11)
            y = y + 1
        Else
            If grsheet.Cells(x, 6) <> Me.cmbprogram Then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

        'issue
        If sdsheet.Cells(x, 7) = Me.cmbissue Then
            'put on grsheet
            grsheet.Cells(y, 1) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 3)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 2) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 4)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 3) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 5)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 4) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 6)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 5) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 7)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 6) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 8)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 7) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 9)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 8) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 10)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 9) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 11)
            y = y + 1
        Else
            If grsheet.Cells(x, 7) <> Me.cmbissue Then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

        'status
        If sdsheet.Cells(x, 11) = Me.cmbstatus Then
            'put on grsheet
            grsheet.Cells(y, 1) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 3)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 2) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 4)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 3) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 5)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 4) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 6)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 5) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 7)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 6) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 8)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 7) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 9)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 8) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 10)
            grsheet.Cells(y, 9) = sdsheet.Cells(x, 11)
            y = y + 1
        Else
            If grsheet.Cells(x, 11) <> Me.cmbstatus Then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'jump to report
    grsheet.Visible = True
    grsheet.Select

    'print preview option
    If Me.cbprintpreview = True Then
        grsheet.PrintPreview
    End If

    'close report
    answer = MsgBox("Would you like to close this report?", vbYesNo, "Close Report?")

    If answer = vbYes Then
        grsheet.Visible = False

        'clear last report
        grsheet.Range("A2:i" & grlr).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the different selections (in different comboboxes) to be combined a "and" (ie. a row must match all selections, not just one) ? Also you're calling Exit For and leaving the loop as soon as you hit a non-matching row: is that what you mean to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Tim! Yes, I would like to combine all selections. Nope, I don't want to leave the loop when there's a non-matching row. I'd like it to keep searching through the data sheet for suitable matches. I'm a super novice so am taking some time getting use to suitable statements... should I delete all 'Exit Fors' and pop some 'And's' in there somewhere? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested. Assumes all your comboboxes have an "All" option:

```
Private Sub btnrun_Click()
    Dim sdsheet As Worksheet, grsheet As Worksheet
    Dim sdlr As Long, grlr As Long, y As Long, x As Long

    Set sdsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Governance Reporting Data")
    Set grsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Governance Report")
    Dim match As Boolean
    match = False

    sdlr = Application.Max(sdsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row, 2)

    '## are you sure you want to get this here?
    grlr = Application.Max(grsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 2)
    y = 2 ' starting row << not grlr ?

    'month
    For x = 5 To sdlr

        If Me.cmbmonth = "All" Or sdsheet.Cells(x, 2) = Me.cmbmonth Then
        If Me.cmbprovider = "All" Or sdsheet.Cells(x, 4) = Me.cmbprovider Then
        If Me.cmbcontractofficer = "All" Or sdsheet.Cells(x, 5) = Me.cmbcontractofficer Then
        If Me.cmbprogram = "All" Or sdsheet.Cells(x, 6) = Me.cmbprogram Then
        If Me.cmbissue = "All" Or sdsheet.Cells(x, 7) = Me.cmbissue Then
        If Me.cmbstatus = "All" Or sdsheet.Cells(x, 11) = Me.cmbstatus Then

            grsheet.Cells(y, 1).Resize(1, 9).Value = sdsheet.Cells(x, 3).Resize(1, 9).Value
            y = y + 1
            match = True

        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
    Next


    grsheet.Visible = True
    grsheet.Activate

    If Me.cbprintpreview = True Then grsheet.PrintPreview

    If MsgBox("Would you like to close this report?", vbYesNo, "Close Report?") = vbYes Then
        grsheet.Visible = False
        grsheet.Range("A2:I" & grlr).ClearContents '<< grlr value will not be current ?
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks, Tim. This is very much appreciated! That's certainly a lot neater than what I had. For the clear contents, I thought 'grlr value' would be based on the current data on worksheet and clear all data present but it seems you are correct. I've just changed the range to a value that the report will never reach (grsheet.Range("A2:I150").ClearContents). Thanks again!